# Yaml comparison using structurediff

Tags: python, yaml

I have a task to create Two YAML files, find the difference and print the higher versions to a file, so i  do some processing, I have created files like below, no specific reason to create YAML file like below, but seems more verbose, but I am getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

Actually I want to do this in Jenkins pipeline, either groovy or python anything works.

Two files: `a.yaml` and `b.yaml`.

#### `a.yaml`

```
fruits: 
  - apples: 1.0
  - grapes: 1.0
  - oranges: 1.0
  
vehicles: 
  - cares: 1.0
  - bikes: 1.0
  - scootors: 1.0
```

#### `b.yaml`

```
fruits: 
  - apples: 2.0
  - grapes: 2.0
  - oranges: 2.0
  
vehicles: 
  - cares: 2.0
  - bikes: 2.0
  - scootors: 2.0
```

I have python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import yaml
import socket
import os

from structurediff import DataComparison, DataFile
comparison = DataComparison(DataFile("a.yaml"), DataFile("b.yaml"), VERBOSITY)
print( "comparison" )
```

Result:

```
root@server01]# python3.6 for-loop.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "for-loop.py", line 7, in <module>
    comparison = DataComparison(DataFile("/my_workspace/teja/yaml/a.yaml"), DataFile("/my_workspace/teja/yaml/b.yaml"), VERBOSITY)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: will you have always the same keys? ('appels','grapes',etc)

Comment: Hmm, your usage looks almost exactly like the example in the [**Project description**](https://pypi.org/project/structurediff/) on pypi for the `structurediff ` module. Suggest you add a `print(type(DataComparison), type(DataFile))` after the `import` and make sure neither one is a module.

Comment: ```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import yaml
import socket
from structurediff import DataComparison, DataFile
print(type(DataComparison), type(DataFile))
comparison = DataComparison(DataFile("a.yaml"), DataFile("b.yaml"), VERBOSITY)
print(comparison)
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import yaml
import socket
from structurediff import DataComparison, DataFile
print(type(DataComparison), type(DataFile))
comparison = DataComparison(DataFile("a.yaml"), DataFile("b.yaml"), VERBOSITY)
print(comparison)
`
error message
`python3.6 for-loop.py 
<class 'module'> <class 'module'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "for-loop.py", line 6, in <module>
    comparison = DataComparison(DataFile("a.yaml"), DataFile("b.yaml"), VERBOSITY)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[root@docswarm01 yaml]`

Comment: Sorry for Bad formatting, i am trying to improve

Comment: Not able to paste the python script as it looks, seems i am missing some backticks to display as code.

Comment: @Niru: Do not use comments for provide code or logs for your question. Instead, [edit] your question post and add code/logs into it. This is how Stack Overflow works: the question post should contain all important information, the comments are just for requesting this information.

Comment: While I don't really see why it would cause this error, `VERBOSITY` seems undefined in your code. Try substituting an actual verbosity value (0-2). Also, did you see this in the package's documentation: *In Python (why would you do this? Use DeepDiff instead!):*